# How to manage Repeater at client end?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater

I have repeater control in which i have implemented Paging. Now its showing 10 data once.
Now i want to manage sorting as well, using jaquery at client end means it will not hit database again for sorting.

Example : Suppose repeater showing 10 items (rows). Each Item Contains Price, Item Count, and date. Now i want sorting feature with in this repeater. so it will sort only in current showing 10 items. sorting feature for all (Price, ItemCount, Date)

I have got some sample in gridview but it's not working repeater please let me know how can i do this. I Searched lot of thing but everything is useless for me.

Comment: can u show ur code how to implement repeater?

Answer (score 0):

For your solution you can visit this [link](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

> tablesorter is a jQuery plugin for
>   turning a standard HTML table with
>   THEAD and TBODY tags into a sortable
>   table without page refreshes.
>   tablesorter can successfully parse and
>   sort many types of data including
>   linked data in a cell. It has many
>   useful features including:
>
> Multi-column sorting Parsers for
>   sorting text, URIs, integers,
>   currency, floats, IP addresses, dates
>   (ISO, long and short formats), time.
>   Add your own easily Support secondary
>   "hidden" sorting (e.g., maintain
>   alphabetical sort when sorting on
>   other criteria) Extensibility via
>   widget system Cross-browser: IE 6.0+,
>   FF 2+, Safari 2.0+, Opera 9.0+ Small
>   code size

Comment: -1 That's not an answer. That's advertisement. Your also assuming he's using a `<table>`

Comment: @Raynos : what r u doing i found here demo of tablesorter

Answer (score 0):

**Pseudo code:**

```
var sortCriteria = ".Price"

var repeaterRows = $(".repeaterRows").detach();
var sortingArray = repeaterRows.map(function(key, val) {
    return {
        "jquery": $(this),
        "sort": $(this).find(sortCriteria).text();
    };
}).get();

sortingArray.sort(function(left, right) {
    return left.sort < right.sort;
});

$.each(sortingArray, function(key, val) {
    val.jquery.appendTo("#repeater");
});
```

First you remove your repeater elements from the container.

Then you map your repeater elements to a wrapper containing the repeater element and something to sort on.

You can then use [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort them by the criteria.

Then iterate over the sorted list and append them to your repeater in the sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use [Jquery tablesorter plugin](http://www.tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html)

Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(".tablesorter") 
        .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}) 
        .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); 
    });
```

aspx markup

```
<table cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
                         <th>Column3</th>
        </tr>

    </tfoot>
         <tbody>
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt_data">
                    <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>

            <td><%#Eval("ColumnName1")%></td>

            <td><%#Eval("ColumnName2")%></td>

            <td><%#Eval("ColumnName3")%></td>

            </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
         </tbody>
</table>

<div id="pager" class="pager">
```

Comment: Use the `<HeadTemplate>` and `<FooterTemplate>` to wrap the header and footer of that html `<table>`. What does `widgets: ['zebra']` mean? Where is the `#pager` markup? -1 Make an effort rather then copy and pasting the jQuery code in the link.

Comment: @Raynos : widgets: ['zebra'] :- style would be look like zebra style. and soerry for page it is my mistake, I implemented successfully one time with repeater not just copy paste...

Comment: @Rayans I provided link also here you can find more details.